# Help understanding equation

Tags: capacitor, schematics, equation

I'm trying to understand the following equation:

1/(2π·R·f) --> 10 μF,  f ~ 0 Hz

It is in this schematic in the bottom left.

[image: Function generator]

I can't seem to find a 10 μF ceramic/film capacitor. I did use ten 104 ceramic caps in parallel as a temporary fix, however, I'm not getting the results I expected on the output of the function generator. I'm wondering if the "10 μF" is a typo and it should be a different value.

Comment: Did you already check here? https://www.instructables.com/Portable-Function-Generator-on-Arduino/

Comment: Have you tried speaking with Faransky?

Comment: 104 capacitors? Do you mean 10 nF?

Comment: 10 μF ceramic and film capacitors are very common and readily available.

Comment: NB @Travalon, the formula is derived from the Fc cutoff frequency formula: 1/(1/2*pi*RC), you can switch C to the front and F(c) to the back. The CAP_ON pin makes it possible to guide the signal just through the relay (directly) or through the capacitor (DC block)

Answer (score 1):

> *I can't seem to find a 10uF ceramic/film capacitor. I did use ten 104
> ceramic caps in parallel as a temporary fix however, I'm not getting
> the results I expected on the output of the function generator.*

A 104 capacitor is 100 nF and ten in parallel makes 1 μF not 10 μF. See the orange box below: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2022/01/capacitor-color-codes.html).

> *I'm wondering if the "10uF" is a typo and it should be a different
> value.*

I don't believe you have any grounds for thinking that.

Comment: @RemyHx, that's the one. But the schematic shows a ceramic/film capacitor not electrolyte.

Comment: @winny Yup, you're right. Let me fix it and see what happens.

Comment: no I have not contacted Faransky. I commented on his post but he hasn't answered in a year or so

Comment: @Travalon are we done here?